# Magento 2: I need to implement google captcha on checkout page(card payments)

Tags: magento2, captcha, recaptcha

I need to implement a google captcha on the checkout page(for card payments).
I am having payment transaction failures with fraudulent orders being placed on the website.
Anyone have solutions for the same.
I have searched on google but didn't get any solutions.
There are so many extensions for captcha but not providing the checkout captcha.

If anyone has any idea about Custom functionality that will also work for me.

Please help with the same.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension for this. I have also used this extension and it's working fine. So this extension is fit for your requirements.
https://webpanda-solutions.com/checkout-captcha.html

Comment: I need a free extension. Can you share the extension?

Comment: What is your Magento version?

Comment: 2.3.5 @amit saini

Comment: do you have please share?

Comment: Sorry, @Shomita, I checked but currently, I have not this extension.